# Source code repository sharing for web apps and mobile apps

Tags: git, xamarin, web-applications, version-control, mobile-application

We're building a web app which exposes a RESTful API and a mobile app consuming
 that API.

These both form part of a product (in a business/marketing sense).

The web app will be deployed in the cloud, and the mobile app will be deployed to app stores for use on mobile devices.

It's unlikely there will be third party consumers of the API.

Both the web app and the mobile app will be developed using the same language (C# - ASP.NET Core and Xamarin) and there is some potential re-use/sharing of code, e.g. models.

We're using Git.

We'll be implementing a continuous delivery pipeline for both the web and mobile apps.

Should the codebases of the web app and the mobile app share the same source code repository or should there be a separate repository for each? What is considered best practice in this scenario?

Comment: if they're sharing code it makes sense to have them in the same repo.  But there are so many factors that drive this decision that there isn't any "right" answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"Best practice" is a little subjective.

In general, I prefer to keep major subsystems in separate repositories. This means they can have their own versioning strategy, and - if necessary - different development teams.

Typically, you want your REST server to have a known versioning strategy, and that's easiest if you have a single repo with it's own release pipeline and version numbers. Depending on your project, you may want your app developers to work against a known, "stable-ish" version of the services, but you want your services team to be able to deploy test versions without affecting the app teams.

You can achieve this with a single repo but it's much easier to build with a dedicated repo for your services.

Comment: Thanks for your input. The more I think about it and the goals of having automated commit to release automation, the more I favour keeping the repositories separate, using package management (i.e. NuGet) to control dependencies and shared models.